# Ionic2 Build folder structure missing

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm starting to learn `Ionic2`, I have created a new project with `ionic start myproject --v2` and everything works correctly if I do `ionic serve`.

The build folder is missing in ionic 2 project folder.

Whenever I am trying to download any existing `Ionic2` template in that one also build folder missing.

```
ionic -v 2.0.0-beta.30
cordova -v 6.2.0
node -v v6.2.1
npm -v 3.9.5
```

[image]

Comment: add --v2 for version2 and --ts for typescript support. This way you will see the app folder

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to add support for the platform/s you are working with, by executing from Ionic CLI console:

```
ionic platform add android
```

or

```
ionic platform add ios
```

And then you should build your project by executing:

```
ionic build android
```

or

```
ionic build ios
```

Comment: ionic2 template missing

Answer (score 1):

your `ionic serve` build is under `www`. The native builds ( from `ionic build`) are under `platform`.

Comment: missing folder attached

Comment: what do you mean missing?

Comment: during install this folder is missing

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I had the same issue and was able to fix it by installing Gulp :

`npm install -g gulp`

Then I did `gulp build`.

This solved my issues and generated the `build` folder as it was supposed to.